# Make interface strings configurable per language, identified by machine name

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

We are building a complex page layout where some labels should be not only translatable, but configurable per language, including English. The display logic is already custom code, so we are quite free for how these labels are stored.

So far we have considered these options:

- Harcode the English version, then call `t()`.
- Create variables for the English version, then call `t()`. (*)
- Create variables for the labels, and mark them as translatable. (*) This requires a dedicated admin form where the labels can be configured in any language.

(*) These two options require a dedicated admin form where the labels can be configured either in English or in all languages. It can be useful to register the variables with [variable](https://drupal.org/project/variable) module.
Of course when I say "variable" I mean those you manage with variable_set() / variable_get().

The question: Is there any alternative to the variable system where such configurable strings can be stored? Ideally something that already gives us an edit UI out of the box, without having to create custom forms..